# Oracle row wise Sum

Tags: oracle

My Oracle Employee_Expense table is as follows. Text in red is what I am expecting.

[image]

I just need to get the sum of the expenses for this four months sorted by Emp_No and Year.

Any ideas please?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them up and include it in your query;

```
SELECT   emp_no
       , year
       , january
       , february
       , march
       , april
       , (january + february + march + april) AS total
FROM     employee_expense
ORDER BY emp_no, year
```

That should do it unless there's something else involved that you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It's a poor design, months shouldn't be the columns of a table.

For scenarios where you need a generated column from other columns, what you may do is add a [**virtual column**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) to the table, i.e. for Total. You then don't have to explicitly write the addition every time you query, simply query the columns and Oracle will do the addition for you.

```
ALTER TABLE employee_expense ADD (
     total GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( january + february + march + april )
);
```

Simply running this will give you the values for Total.

```
select * from employee_expense;
```

Comment: Nice update Kaushik Nayak.I ve not been aware about Virtual columns.Cheers